# Ongoing Availability

Tags: word-meaning

I am not sure about this:

> [link](http://latimesblogs.latimes.com/lanow/2013/01/teacher-who-appeared-in-porn-film-awaits-vote-on-pay.html)
>   Although Halas filmed the pornographic scenes before she was employed at the middle school -- between 2005 and 2006 -– the ***ongoing availability*** of the videos will impede her ability to be an effective teacher, wrote Judge Julie Cabos-Owen.

"*Ongoing*" seems to fit an activity or event better, not a quality.  "*Availability*" is a quality.  So, is the usage in the example sentence wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In this case it means the "*State*" of being **Available** - which is "Ongoing"

Answer (score 1):

"ongoing availability" here is a way to substantivize the adjective phrase [still available]. Another option would have been to write:

"the fact that these videos are still available, will impede..."

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not wrong. *Availability* here is not a 'quality' but a *state*, the state of being available, which may have temporal and even spatial extension.

> This offer is available through September 30.
>   These hams are available at fine grocers everywhere.
>   These videos will continue to be available in the future.

Comment: +1 I like your way of explanation which I can apply elsewhere. ^_^